# Specifying select : false on array of subdocuments in Schema

Tags: mongoose

I'm looking for help on the proper syntax for turning off select of property which is an array of subdocuments. I was hoping for something along these lines:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema(
    {  
        fb_id       : Number, 
        children    : [{ type: CustomChildSchema,select:false}]
    }
)
```

`children` array has the potential to grow exponentially, so I'm trying to keep these out of query results unless explicitly asked for.

Comment: Which version of mongoose do you use?

Answer (score 7):

I came up with a similar problem and solved it using the slightly altered syntax below

```
var UserSchema = new Schema(
    {  
        fb_id       : Number, 
        children    : { type: [CustomChildSchema], select:false}
    }
)
```