# Mongoose select:false an array of ObjectIds

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to do something very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374293/specifying-select-false-on-array-of-subdocuments-in-schema), except that I do not want to reference the child object's schema directly. I'm using the ObjectId & Ref notation:

```
children: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SomeSchema' }]
```

Is there anyway to achieve this? I don't see anything in the docs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In retrospect, this should have been obvious:

```
children: { 
    type: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'SomeSchema'}],  
    select: false 
}
```

Comment: You saved my day, thanks for answer as well as question

Comment: But how to push data in this `children` because when I am trying to push new `ObjectId` as `parent.children.push(id)`, it is showing push for undefined property error. Any help

Comment: I don't know it is valid but I have found a workaround for the issue, I just needed to add a check if the property is undefined initialize it to `[]`

Comment: It's 2018 and still relevant and working without any breaking changes