# how to exclude array type fields with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this:

```
var CitySchema   = new Schema({
    name: {type : String, required : true},
    region: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Region', required : true},
    images: [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image', select: false}]
});
```

When I do query on the collection, the field images would still show up even when I put the `select: false`. How can I hide the field without using `.select('-images')`?

Comment: Can you show us the query at hand?

Comment: `City.find({}).sort('name').lean().exec(function(err, cities) { console.log(cities); });`

Comment: Have you tried `City.find({}, 'name region').sort('name').lean().exec(function(err, cities) { console.log(cities); })`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying select : false on array of subdocuments in Schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374293/specifying-select-false-on-array-of-subdocuments-in-schema)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are putting `select: false`, you say to exclude values **inside** the `images` array. You need to put `select: false` for the `images` array itself.

Look at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17374293/specifying-select-false-on-array-of-subdocuments-in-schema).

---

**Applied to your case**:

```
var CitySchema   = new Schema({
    name: {type : String, required : true},
    region: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Region', required : true},
    images: { 
      type: [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Image', select: false}],
      select: false, 
    },
});
```